# Custom domain used with Hotmail account expired, still can log in, but not receive

Tags: domain, outlook.com

I had linked a free co.cc domain name to create a Hotmail account which has now expired. I no longer have access to that domain, and I don't have access to that account on the co.cc registrar.

I'm not getting any emails sent to that email ID, although I can login to that account and use it as a Microsoft account in all Microsoft services.

And now I can't change that account ID also.

Any solution other than deleting that account?

Answer (score 1):

Changing your account details is fairly easy.

1. Go to https://account.live.com/Notifications and log in
2. Click on **Notifications** and add an account with **Manage email preferences**

   [image]
3. Once you have verified your new account you will be able to change the **Preferred email address** and remove the redundant one.

   [image]